# Quick variable question

Tags: scope

I have an EditText object  (et_travel) on my screen that's asking for miles traveled.  I grab that data like this:

```
        float travel = Float.parseFloat(et_travel.getText().toString());
            if(travel > 40000){
```

I just discover that if someone puts 40000 in the EditText, everything works fine, but if they put 40,000 (adding a comma to the number), I force close on the float travel = ...statement.

How can I evaluate the number without having a problem from the user adding a comma?

Comment: what technology is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this in Java? It appears to be, but I'm wondering if I'm mistaken. Regardless, I would suggest you remove all of the characters from the string that are not of a numeric type. A way to do this may be using a regular expression.

A way to do this in Java may be the following:

```
String input = et_travel.getText().toString();
input = input.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
float travel = Float.parseFloat(input);
...
```

This way, you strip anything that is a non-numeric value from the string first, and then attempt to do your work. Obviously do some error checking before this (like input is not null and such). **One change that is needed however** is that you may need to maintain the '.' character (if you're given non-integer values). This would require changing the first regex a bit.

Check here: [http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is some validation on the input.  Before converting the string into a float parse the string.  If there are any ','s then remove them.  If there is just junk then reject the input, otherwise someone could put a word or anything else in the input and cause havoc in your program.

Answer (score 0):

Check out 
[inputType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType) to restrict user input

```
android:inputType="number"
```